# How to write where clause in pivot statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get records based on project and year

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         Source,
         val,
         month
     FROM   
         tbl_OrganicResult
     CROSS APPLY 
         (VALUES ('visitors', visitors),
                 ('UniqueVisitors', UniqueVisitors),
                 ('ReturnVisitors', ReturnVisitors)) cs (Source, val)) A  
PIVOT (Max(val)
FOR month IN ([jun], [jul)) pv
```

I need the records with where condition like

```
select * 
from tbl_OrganicResult 
where project = 'Homeocare'
```

Sample data

```
ProjectName Month  Year      visitors   UniqueVisitors  ReturnVisitors
Homeocare   Jun    2015      400        33              22
Homeocare   Jul    2015      100        10              8
debug test. Aug    2015      15222      122             120
debug test. Jun.   2015      1500       150             15
debug test. Jul    2015      1400       140             14
```

I'm getting records like this which is not correct, I mean I'm not getting project wise.

How to add where condition to get like where project - 'homeocare' ?

Getting output like this

```
Source             jun         jul
ReturnVisitors     8           120
UniqueVisitors     10          122
Visitors           100         15222
```

I need records like this

```
Source                jun    jul
ReturnVisitors.       22     8
UniqueVisitors.       33     10
Visitors              400    100
```

Sorry for my mistake of giving wrong data (earlier). Here always getting last 2 records and not used where condition to get records project and year wise.

Comment: for jun visitors are 400 then why are showing it in jul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause should go after the `cross apply` like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM   
    (
    SELECT 
         Source,
         val,
        Year,
         month
     FROM   
         tbl_OrganicResult        
     CROSS APPLY 
         (VALUES ('visitors', visitors),
                 ('UniqueVisitors', UniqueVisitors),
                 ('ReturnVisitors', ReturnVisitors)) cs (Source, val)
     WHERE ProjectName = 'Homeocare' 
    ) A  
PIVOT ( Max(val) FOR Month IN ([jun], [jul]) ) pv
```

Unless you only have data for one year in your table this query will get you the max value for a month from any year where you have data recorded for that month, for example if you had 100 visitors in June 15 and 200 visitors in June 14 then the value for June 14 would be selected. This might not be what you want.

I would consider doing something like this instead:

```
SELECT 
    Source, [Jun-2015], [Jul-2015]
FROM   
    (
    SELECT 
         Source,
         Val,
        MonthYear = CONCAT(Month,'-',Year)
     FROM   
         tbl_OrganicResult        
     CROSS APPLY 
         (VALUES ('Visitors', visitors),
                 ('UniqueVisitors', UniqueVisitors),
                 ('ReturnVisitors', ReturnVisitors)) cs (Source, Val)
     WHERE ProjectName = 'Homeocare'
    ) A  
PIVOT ( MAX(Val) FOR MonthYear IN ([Jun-2015], [Jul-2015]) ) pv ;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case you have three months but you are looking for july in place of june and August in place of july just add alias names for those columns

```
declare @table table (ProjectName varchar(20), Month  varchar(20),  Year varchar(20),   visitors INT,   UniqueVisitors INT,  ReturnVisitors INT)
insert into @table (ProjectName,Month,Year,visitors,UniqueVisitors,ReturnVisitors)values 
('Homeocare' ,  'Jun'  ,  2015 ,   400  ,          33     ,         22),
('Homeocare' ,  'Jul' ,   2015 ,   100 ,            10   ,           8),
('debug test',  'Aug' ,   2015 ,   15222  ,        122  ,          120 ) 



SELECT source,JUN as Jul,jul as aug FROM   (SELECT Source,
               val,
               month
        FROM   @table
               CROSS apply (VALUES ('visitors',visitors),
                                   ('UniqueVisitors',UniqueVisitors),
                                   ('ReturnVisitors',ReturnVisitors)) cs (Source, val)) A  
       PIVOT (max(val)
             FOR month IN ([jun],[Jul],
                           [Aug])) pv
```